# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response for ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

Tags: java, jsp

Getting exception as `getOutputStream()` has already been called for this response when using

```
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

in my code.
Here is the sample code. First i'm placing the input file in my local path which is a svg image. After that svg is converted into png and get downloaded from browser.

```
{ //code to write image into local path
                    File filesvg = new File(inFile); 
                    svg  = svg.replace("1e-006","0.000001");
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filesvg);
                    writer.write(svg);
                    writer.close();
                    //here some lines of code to convert to png
                    return outFile;
                    }
                    //Code to download image from browser.
                    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                       "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + ext + "\"");
                        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
                        ServletOutputStream outputStream = 
                        response.getOutputStream();
                        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
                        int byteRead;
                        while ((byteRead = fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096)) 
                       != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(outputByte, 0, byteRead);
                        }
                        fileIn.close();
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your entire method ?

Comment: To state the obvious: you have already called `getOutputStream()` (maybe during a method call).

Comment: Do you call  getOutputStream() in a jsp ?

Comment: Yes the entire block is in jsp..

Comment: after adding out.clear and out = pageContext.pushBody(); working fine